# use `mv` command and my file gone

Tags: linux, command-line

i want to move myfile.tar.gz to folder

My command is

```
  mkdir backup
  mv myfile.tar.gz /backup
```

arrrgh, and the file gone
in /backup directory not exist, try using `find` command not shown

how to find it?

Thank you

Comment: check your root folder / for file named backup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a directory called `backup`under the directory where you were at that moment.

However you moved the file `myfile.tar.gz` to `/backup`. The `/` means that you moved the file to a new file called backup under directory `/`.

The only thing you did was **rename** `myfile.tar.gz` to `backup` and put it under  `/`.